# solr PDF and word wrap

Tags: pdf, solr, word-wrap

I am using Solr to index PDF documents.
Everything works well, but there is one problem. If a word in a PDF document has been wrapped to another line, then it is indexed as part of the word plus a hyphen. For example, text like this:

*We ran to the beach. We heard more guns, then every-*

*thing was quiet and a flag went up above the trees.*

Here the word *everything* is broken into parts *every-* and *thing*. Now if I search for *everything*, I will not be able to find this document. How to do it right in this case?

Comment: here either you need to correct the document or can apply a pattern to remove the - and append the words...But the latter suggestion is not good ...I think it is wise to correct the documents or you would need to add many patches like this

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to correct the documents. Besides, there are a lot of them

Comment: I think it can be possible to make a replacement during indexing? replace('-\n', '')? Is there any way to do this in solr?

Comment: you can add the regex in you fieldtype and the filter to add is PatternReplaceCharFilter. you can refer more here https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html   <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="-" replacement=""/>
</analyzer>

Comment: You're probably going to have to use an update processor or a char filter factory to handle this in any useful way, since it'll otherwise have been broken up into several tokens before it can be read - another option is to create your own filter from the shinglefilter that looks for tokens ending with `-` and then combining them with the next token if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

With the advice of Abhijit Bashetti and MatsLindh, the problem was solved. In my schema.xml I added the line

```
<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\-\n" replacement=""/>
```

After that, the word wrap does not interfere with the search.